# Displaying a var using AngularJS/HTML on the screen

Tags: angularjs

I'm using MEAN Stack to construct my web application. (Mongo, Express, Angular, NodeJS) I have a server.js file, html file and a css file. My server.js generates a var number which I want to get rendered on the frontend, however I'm having some trouble doing that. Let me explain, on my html there a button I created, whenever the user clicks on that button, I want this specific var to be shown the screen, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code for the creation of the button:
      
        Some Text

Below is the angularjs code for where I use the exact rendering to be occurred:

### The Amount:

### {{links.amountLinks}}

### test this

My server.js code:(Please note I'm using jsdom module)

var jsdom = require("jsdom");

```
  jsdom.env(
          url,
          ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
          function (err, window) {
          // console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length, "io.js releases!");
          // alert("there have been", window.$("a").length, "io.js releases!");
          console.log(window.$("a").length);
          amountLinks = window.$("a").length;
          json.amountLinks = amountLinks;
          data = amountLinks;
  });
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello @Code_Master, welcome to SO. It would be easy for the community to help you out if you can add relevant accompanying code to the question, directly or on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be fixed as follow:

```
  jsdom.env(
          url,
          ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
          function (err, window) {
          // console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length, "io.js releases!");
          // alert("there have been", window.$("a").length, "io.js releases!");
          console.log(window.$("a").length);
          amountLinks = window.$("a").length;
          json.amountLinks = amountLinks;
          data = amountLinks;
          res.send(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4))
  });
}
```